Issue in converting v8::Local<v8::Data> to v8::Local<v8::Value>
I have a v8 method which returns type v8::Local<v8::Data>. I want to convert this to type v8::Local<v8::Value>. Value is a child class of Data (ref).
I tried using Data class methods like isValue, isModule, etc to try to convert Data into its child class, but it does not resolve to any
  // GetModuleRequests is a v8 method
  Local<FixedArray> moduleR = referrer->GetModuleRequests();
  for (int i = 0, length = moduleR->Length(); i < length; ++i) {
    Local<Data> moduleRequests = moduleR->Get(context, i);
  }

I tried this
Local<FixedArray> moduleR = referrer->GetModuleRequests();

      for (int i = 0, length = moduleR->Length(); i < length; ++i) {
        Local<Data> moduleRequests = moduleR->Get(context, i);
        Local<Value> FinalVal = Local<Value>();
        if(moduleRequests->IsValue()) {
          Local<Value> module = moduleRequests.As<Value>();
          FinalVal = module
        } else {
          std::cout<<"moduleRequests is not a value\n";
        }

Another approach was to
Local<Value> someValue = Local<Value>::New(isolate, moduleRequests);

Is there any other way to cast this?

It's unclear what you tried where you failed, what modReq is, Can you post a more code, [mcve] and add more details?

@273K added a example of the code

If moduleRequests.isValue() is not true, then it's not a value, it can be another fixed array, or object, or private..., or length is zero.

@273K i checked for all the values (object , functionTemplate, context) but the it does not resolve to any child values

referrer->GetModuleRequests() returns a local v8::FixedArray of v8::ModuleRequest. It does not reflect any of the "is" checks of v8::Data. Try
moduleRequests.As<v8::ModuleRequest>();


Fixed array class has a Get method which returns Local hence the moduleRequests is of type v8::Localv8::Data

Found an workaround for this particular usecase.
I casted my variable moduleRequests( type v8::Local<v8::Data> to v8::Local<v8::ModuleRequests> ) and we have a method GetSpecifier() on ModuleRequests class that returns v8::Local<v8::String>. Here String is a child class of type Value
Local<String> stringSpecifier = Local<ModuleRequest>::Cast(moduleR->Get(context, i))->GetSpecifier();

